# Would there be any enthusiasm for a single "general theory resources" thread?

Tags: discussion

This community has decided that asking for links to resources is off-topic, for understandable reasons (e.g. we're trying to be 'the resource' ourselves, and there's a risk of link rot).

However, we do get questions where our answer (or close comment) ends up being along the lines of "you should go and learn some theory".

Would there be any enthusiasm here for creating a single, curated question containing links to good resources? Has there been any discussion about this already?

Maybe there's a good list off-site that we could point people to?

Or maybe we don't want to get involved in this kind of thing?

Answer (score 8):

This reminds me of the situation for book recommendations over on Stack Overflow. In particular, I'm thinking of the old community wiki (now removed) that held book recommendations for learners of the C programming language at various stages of development. Eventually, the page became a real mess. Anyone could post an answer with their pet recommendations, or anyone could edit new entries into some of the more popular lists on the page. There were some classics, some great books, some useful books, and some worthless books; the page was useless for anyone looking for a solid recommendation because it was just a bunch of lists of everything available. Even worse, some books were championed by some users and despised by others. You might as well just use a search engine to find learning resources.

I am afraid that the same thing will happen if we try to start a community wiki for general music theory resources. Before long there will be lots of suggestions, lots of noise, conflicting opinions, and no way for a neophyte to judge the merits of those suggestions. A learner would have to use a search engine to find reviews and recommendations to validate the resources listed here; why not just start with the search engine?

Comment: You make valid points! I think I do prefer Dom's idea of a chat - it wouldn't 'claim' to be tidy.

Answer (score 7):

Before suggested an question and answer post dedicated to this, we do have other venues to explore first.

Community adds are a good way to get community to support external resources. musictheory.net and IMSLP are already advertised though this and we can and should add any resources we deem important and are good sources of theory for lessons and source material respectively.

We can also set up a chat for this which may be a better first go at trying to see as how we as a community handle it.. Resource post require a *lot* of maintenance and having a chat dedicated to it would be a good preface to how well we could take care of it.

Comment: Chat sounds a good idea too, and would have the nice property of 'fresher' links being automatically in more recent posts. I remember the community ads, but you presumably can only have so many of those.

Comment: How searchable is chat history? Or would it not be a problem if a resource is requested multiple times?

Comment: @marcellothearcane It's searchable by word and things can be started which make them easy to find later.

Answer (score 2):

Every tag has its own wiki which is perfect for collecting useful links. Edit these into the [theory tag info](https://music.stackexchange.com/tags/theory/info) and then point users to that.